# How do I change the default local hard drive free space when using iCloud on OSX?

Tags: macos, icloud, hard-drive, catalina

I'm using iCloud to add additional storage to my Macbook. I'm trying to upload some or external hard drives, but it's a slow process since I can't extend the free space.

Is there a way to change the default free space on my local harddrive that way I can force more storage onto the cloud?

Comment: Can't you just install macOS onto a larger external drive with more space, upload to iCloud, then boot back to your smaller volume?  Depending on your Mac you would have to allow external booting in Recovery.

Comment: That's not really how it works.  You can't simply buy cloud storage to increase the storage on your physical device. If you need more space on your machine you need to add it there (i.e.USB drive, larger drive/ssd, etc.)  That said...what is "default free space?"  Free space is what you haven't used and there's  no setting anywhere for storage you've yet to consume.

Comment: @Allan "When storage space is needed, only the files you recently opened are kept on your Mac, so that you can easily work offline." https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206996

Comment: @Allan This implies that there is a default free space size that allows iCloud to know when to remove files from your disc to keep them in the cloud.

Comment: It's not based on some set amount of free space because the amount you need is impossible to predict.  It's based on use.  If it's in your iCloud folder and use it a lot, it will be cached locally for offline use.  If you hardly touch the app/file, it will be offloaded to conserve space.

Comment: @Allen from my past experience it currently seems to be about 30GB for the default from the last few sessions of adding files and waiting for iCloud to catch up and clear up space.

Comment: That's not how it works.  It's based on [recently accessed files](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206996).  If it worked they way you describe, if you downloaded a 25GB file (a movie perhaps), how would it free up the 25GB to get to the default 30?  What would it send to icloud that already wasn't there?  Remember, iCloud only applies to Documents and such, not system files or files outside of iCloud Drive (local to your computer).

Comment: @Allan it does if you move all the files you want in iCloud to the iCloud folder....

Comment: *it does if you move all...* Then they're no longer outside the iCloud folder and you can't move system files at all.  I realize it appears to work the way you've observed, but it's not configured that way.  You're trying to look for a solution based on how it doesn't work.

Comment: @Allen How does iCloud know to "optimize storage" (taking files off my physical disc and only storing them on the cloud) if there isn't a default "free space" that it is observing and maintaining?

Comment: @Allen About your comment about frequently used files: if space is insufficient, even open files are removed from your Mac and one has to re-download them to carry on working with them, or saving them. The best option to achieve the OP's intended result seems to be my first suggestion/question (as long as a larger external drive is available).

Comment: @Redarm Thank you for the suggestion. Although I have plenty of iCloud storage available and this does not resolve my original ask.

Comment: This is the confusing part @Redarm, you (via your initial comment) agree with me that she needs a *larger* physical drive whether external or internal, but then both disagree how iCloud operates because reasons.  I've provided links that describe how iCloud works, but if it's not to your liking..that's cool.  The solution is that she needs more *local* space.  Period.  There's no magic command that's going to change that.

Comment: Don't take my word for it...Take Apple's [*Turn on Optimize Mac Storage. Then your Mac keeps all of your **recent** files on your computer, but keeps your **older** ones only in iCloud*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985) and [*When storage space is needed...files that you **seldom** use are stored in iCloud automatically*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206996).  All refer to *age based rules* (seldom used, and recent files).  Nothing references "default free space"

Comment: @Allan I'm open to the idea that there may not be an interface for the concept of "default free space", but can't imagine how this system would work without the concept somewhere.

Comment: @Allan The second description is just personal experience - packing my system into a very small volume, the system becomes quite aggressive at removal.  I've long complained about the removal of open iCloud files in e.g. Affinity Designer, when space goes down to 5 GB (only a temp file is kept, which can't be saved and a manual re-download is necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears at this time, that if the concept of "default free local hard drive space" exists, it is not accessible through any known interface. Not the user interface or terminal.